# Mysql Update wtih Join and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to update table using join and limit. I construct this query

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 AS b
ON table1.id = b.id
SET 
table1.username = b.post_username
WHERE b.post_username != ''
AND table1.username = ''
LIMIT 10
```

unfortunaetly I recive error:

```
Error Code: 1221
Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you cannot use limit like this to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that:

If you read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) it says:

> With no WHERE clause, all rows are updated. If the ORDER BY clause is
>   specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The
>   LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.
>
> **For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case,
>   ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.**

So you can't do that in your query.

Answer (score 0):

hey just Delete `LIMIT 10` from your code

Comment: Sorry, but those modifications accomplish similar results in any query. And they can only be used to update a single table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query syntax:

```
update work_to_do as target
   inner join (
      select w. client, work_unit
      from work_to_do as w
         inner join eligible_client as e on e.client = w.client
      where processor = 0
      order by priority desc
      limit 10
   ) as source on source.client = target.client
      and source.work_unit = target.work_unit
   set processor = @process_id;
```